# Automatização chamada utilizando curl - Jmeter

Tags: testes, automatização, testes-automatizados, jmeter

Boa tarde pessoal!

Como procedo para adicionar no Jmeter uma chamada por curl, a fim de obter meu header para utilizar nos testes posteriormente?

É qual elemento de teste? HTTP request mesmo?

Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue a curl:
curl -X POST -vu xxx:b57f4a4f-a455-4014-9ac8-87c6dac7e8d3 
https://apibpp.xvv.com.br/api/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" 
-d "password=xxxx&username=yyyy&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write"

Obrigado

Comment: Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Pessoal? A minha dúvida mantém-se... rs

Comment: Pessoa, alguém?